# SQL query return all the records where at least one column matches inside a subgroup in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have table  `messages`  in postgresql where each record is a message with the fields: `id, session_creation_time, customer_id, message`
I first need to group the messages into pairs of `session_creation_time` and `customer_id` so I can figure out which messages where part of the same conversation session so I could do do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
GROUP BY session_creation_time, customer_id, id 
ORDER BY session_creation_time
```

And after that I need return all of the messages grouped by session_creation_time and customer_id in which at least one of those messages matches my operator `message ilike "%myString%"`

Any ideas?

**sample data**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |session_creation_time| customer_id | msg_to | msg_from | message |    
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
1   | 2019-10-22 14:43:04 | a           |   a    |   me     | hello   |
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
2   | 2019-10-22 14:43:04 | a           |   me   |   a      | hi      |
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
3   | 2019-10-21 14:43:04 | b           |   me   |   b      |ru there?|
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
4   | 2019-10-21 14:43:04 | b           |   b    |  me      |   yes   |
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
5   | 2019-10-21 14:43:04 | b           |   me   |   b      | help pls|
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
6   | 2019-10-21 14:43:04 | b           |   b    |  me      |I'll help|
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
7   | 2019-10-25 14:43:04 | b           |   me   |   b      |hi its'me|
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
8   | 2019-10-25 14:43:04 | b           |   b    |  me      |welcome  |
----|---------------------|-------------|--------|----------|---------|
```

**expected outcome**

If my operator is `message ilike '%help%'` My query should return messages with the id's : 3,4,5,6  as those are the messages from the same pair of of ``` session_creation_time`` and ```customer_id`where at least one of the messages has the string`help``` on it. and ignore the rest of the messages

Comment: Please add in your question a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along those lines:

```
SELECT m.session_creation_time, m.customer_id, m.message
FROM messages AS m
INNER JOIN messages AS m_
ON m.session_creation_time = m_.session_creation_time
AND m.customer_id = m_.customer_id
WHERE m_.message ilike "%myString%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the columns that you need a group results for and then include the condition to filter out the rows, like so

SELECT COUNT(customer_id), customer_id, session_creation_time
FROM messages 
WHERE message LIKE '%somestring%'
GROUP BY session_creation_time, customer_id
ORDER BY session_creation_time

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that didn't work I got only messages that matched my like conditions instead of a series of the whole conversation of same ```customer_id``` and ```session_creation_time``` where at least one of the many messages did in fact matched my like expression. 

I searched several articles about subqueries and the exists clause But can't figure it out